# How to dynamically compute the bandpass filter coefficients in a Matlab/Simulink?

Tags: matlab, filter, simulink

I have a Simulink model in which I would like to change (at runtime) the central frequency and bandwidth of a bandpass filter. I would like to change these values using slider gains (and eventually a GUI).

I know I can specify the filter coefficients in the input ports of a Digital Filter block, but the missing step is: how do I compute the filter coefficients dynamically? In order to do this I've tried to use an Embedded MATLAB function that includes the `fdesign.lowpass` and `design` methods. Nonetheless Simulink does not seem to allow the dot notation for Embedded MATLAB functions. I've also tried to manually define the data-structure defined by fdesign.lowpass but it also complains.

Have you ever dealt with similar problem? Any help or hint would be very much appreciated!

Kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find a workaround for this problem.

Instead of using `fdesign.bandpass` and `design` methods, one could still use an Embedded MATLAB function and use the function `fir1`. This allows to compute the filter for a given order and cut off frequencies without problems.

Hope this helps